# How can a goto find the address of label if it appears below the goto statement?

Tags: c, goto

When a label is placed below the goto statement, how does the compiler find the address of label to jump? C programming is a top-down approach right ?
If the label is above the goto statement, it is understandable that the address of label is known while it has reached the goto statement. Anyone please explain..

Comment: How can it find the closing bracket of the open one? The compiler is multi-pass, even though it's "top-down".

Comment: It can just store zero and  make a note that it needs to fill in the proper address later, and when it later on sees the label go back and fill in the address.

Comment: You seem to be trying to fit C semantics to a pre-conceived model ("top-down", whatever that means to you) instead of adapting your model to C's actual semantics.  To the extent that C being top-down would prevent `goto` branching to a label that appears later in the source, C is not top-down.

Comment: Because compilers do two passes through the source code.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no requirement that C programs be compiled in a single pass, or just get to look at the source once.

You can even call functions without knowing where they are, trusting the linker to resolve the symbol (much) later than when you run the compiler.

Comment: is it that the older compilers don't do, but the newer compiler do..?

Comment: @HarikrishnanVNair No, C has worked like that for a long time. It is not generally using single-pass compilers as far as I know.

Comment: @HarikrishnanVNair, `goto` has been in C from the beginning.  It has always worked as it now does.  Even the very first C compilers handled forward branches, as indeed BASIC and Fortran compilers, among others, also do.

Comment: I just confused it with the transfer of control to function definition from a function call.
A function definition should be defined above the function call, because then only the compiler knows the address of the function defintion to jump to. Isn't that right? Why won't the same apply to goto-label also ?

Comment: @HarikrishnanVNair No, that is not right. It should be *declared*, so the compiler can check that the call has the proper types for all arguments (and the return value), but that does *not* mean that the address of the target function has to be known. Read up on "linking".